# How to update ckeditor to v5 in laravel-backpack?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-backpack

I want to update ckeditor from version 4 to version 5 inside my laravel-backpack installation. 
Since the ckeditor package is part of the laravel-backpack installation, I don't know how to update it separately.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. You can overwrite an existing field type by [publishing it in your own project](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-how-to#publish-a-column-field-filter-button-and-modify-it): `php artisan backpack:crud:publish fields/ckeditor`.

Any changes you make in the generated file, in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/ckeditor.blade.php` will be for your project, and your project only.

The easiest would be to change the required CSS and JS, from v4 to v5, using CKeditor's DNS. That way you wouldn't have to put any new CSS and JS into your project.

Hope it helps.